# Swift exmperimenting for non-OS X Owners

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I'de like to experiment with iOS development. I don't have any iOS/OS X device, which I understand and accept it's a must, but I do want to experiment with Swift programming language at least.

Is there any way to experiment with Swift programming on Linux (or any other available operating system), or an on-line Swift playground I can run Swift code on, or any Cloud IDE that runs on OS X Virtual machine? Actually, the last option (Cloud IDE) will be the best option fit for me.

Any other free solution to JUST EXPERIMENT with Swift programming will be welcomed!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RunSwift](http://www.runswiftlang.com/) to try Swift in your browser.

From the site:

> While you cannot import abitrary modules, a small subset of Foundation is included.

There is also the potential to run OSX within a VMWare or Virtualbox instance, you can [follow the guide here](http://www.macbreaker.com/2014/05/os-x-mavericks-in-virtualbox-with-niresh.html) and then just install XCode and play with Swift using that.

Comment: Note that there are multiple legal issues with installing OSX on anything but actual Apple hardware.

Comment: Yeah I was toying with whether or not to mention that but as that is mentioned in the guide I'm not here to provide legal counsel heh.